# SAP JCo creating a record in SAP system using Java

Tags: java, jco

I am trying to create an entry in SAP system with the functions and structures I got from ABAP.
I was referring to this link
[Creating Purchase Info Record in SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534602/creating-purchase-info-record-in-sap)

The same problem happens to me. I could not see the record. When we are checking ERRORS as suggested by the above post.... We got this error..

> RFC_ERROR_SYSTEM_FAILURE: THE CURRENT APPLICATION TRIGGERED A
> TERMINATION WITH A SHORT DUMP.

Comment: you've got an abap dump. You'll have to look into transaction st22 on the abap backendto get the line in the function module, as well as the line

Comment: now we can  create data in SAP .But still showing dump error in java console as well as in SAP.thank you , we did what u have told...now we are looking at how to rectify this problem.can u give any suggestions.

Comment: we may help, but we would need at least some info. the code of the funcytion, line causing the dump (from st22) and kind of error...

Comment: JCoFunction function = destinations.getRepository().getFunction("xxx_xxx_xxxx");

Comment: i meant the abap function. the problem is on the abap side, not on the java side.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a short dump, we need to check the transaction code [ST22](https://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/tran/st22.html) to check the exact error for the issue. Then we can adjust the calling code according to the dump details.